# Android Kitkat certification issue when making network request

Tags: android, okhttp

The issue I was running into was

> java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

However, I found the solutions to those problem. But my question now is, did Android/Google implement some kind of enforcement that forces apps to add the certs of dev servers into the apps? For the record, my app successfully made network requests to my server without any sort of certificate setup on January of this year but I checked my app again and the network requests failed a few days ago. So was there some kind of notice that Google put out in the time span?

Comment: Perhaps the SSL certificate expired or was replaced in the intervening months.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't know if that is true. When I go to the url on Chrome, it has the "Secure" thing next to the url. However, something I just stumbled upon was https://security.googleblog.com/2018/03/distrust-of-symantec-pki-immediate.html after going on the developer console on chrome. Do you happen to know if this could be the case?

Comment: I have not heard that those policies were being extended to Android, though I cannot rule it out, either.